# How to access child window from parent window through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose we open a popup through javascript when a link is clicked on parent window.

As everybody knows that parent window elements can be accessed from child window using the **window.opener()** function.

Is it possible to do exactly reverse ? Can parent window access the information about the child window ?

Comment: Please check other similar questions on stackoverflow before asking... Solution has already been given 1000 times...

Comment: There is no similar question on stackoverflow for this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
a=window.open()
a.document.write("<div id='mydiv'>test</div>")
a.document.getElementById("mydiv")
```

Comment: how to access the window object from the returned reference ?
I need to know if the opened window is in focus or not ?

Answer (score 6):

When you open a `window` through `javascript's` [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open) function it returns you a `reference` of the child window.

Using this reference you can access `elements` of the child window, required it complies with [Same origin policy](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/same-origin.html) security requirements.

Comment: How can I access a window that was opened by anchor tag?

Comment: @habib : Unless there is JavaScript triggered by the anchor tag's onclick event, you'll get a new window with a completely separate DOM. The new window will know the page it was opened from (document.referrer), but neither can access the other's state.