# How to execute a javascript function in a new window on a buttonclick in html

Tags: javascript, html, api, jitsi, jitsi-meet

How to call a javascript function(Jitsi Meet API) on button click and open the result(meeting) in a new window, in this case the function has to open up a new Jitsi meeting
I have a javascript function that calls the Jitsi Meet API and opens up or launches a new meeting on button click?

```
//Javascript function to launch the meeting on the button click
 $('#btnStart').on('click',function(){
    Launch();//need to open the new window here and execute this function in new page
   });
```

As of now, the meeting launches on the same page, It would be really helpful if the meeting opens up in a new window on button click.

In simple terms, button click on this page should open up a new window and execute the function in the new window. I want to know how this can be achieved and by using what method.Do guide with an example snippet

Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Launch Page</title>>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="javascript.js"></script>

<script>

    $('#btnStart').on('click',function(){
    Launch();
   });

</script>

</head>

<body >

<div id='meet'>
<button id='btnStart' class ="button">Launch</button> 
</div>>

</body>

</html>
```

Below is the function and the file that has to be executed in a new window on button click- javascript.js

```
var api=null;

function Launch(){
 
 const domain = 'your.domain.com' 
  const options = {
      roomName:'room123',
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      parentNode:document.querySelector('#meet'),
      interfaceConfigOverwrite: {  SHOW_JITSI_WATERMARK: true,SHOW_WATERMARK_FOR_GUESTS: true, DEFAULT_BACKGROUND: "#212529", 
      DEFAULT_LOCAL_DISPLAY_NAME: 'oc' ,TOOLBAR_BUTTONS: [
        'microphone', 'camera', 'desktop', 'fullscreen',
        'fodeviceselection', 'recording', 'profile', 'chat',
        'settings', 'raisehand','info','hangup',
        'videoquality', 'filmstrip', 'stats',
        'tileview'
    ]}
  };

    api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain,options);  
 
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890599/how-to-access-child-window-from-parent-window-through-javascript for some guidance on executing actions in a popup window.

Comment: Thank you @Nathan, but it does not satisfy the requirement, do send me if there are more related reference.Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a while, I finally figured it out

I made use of the `window.open()` in the current HTML script to open up  new window and made use of `document.ready(){}` and loaded the script inside this function on loading the new window.

Voila!! It worked as per my requirement instead of calling the javascript on src i.e.,

`<script src ="example.js"></script>`

> If you want to open a document/html in a new window and not tab on button click or link use the `window.open()` as shown below
> Syntax
> `window.open(URL, name, specs, replace)`
>
> > `window.open("example.html","windowname","_blank","height=500,width=500");`

This is what my function looks like now after modification

```
example.html

<html>
 
 <head>
    
     <title>Welcome to My HTML</title>

     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
 
     <script>
        
             $(function(){

               $('#btnStart').on('click',function(){
                             
                 window.open("example2.html","newWindow","_blank","height=500,width=500");    
                
               });
               
             });
             
     </script>
 
 </head>

  <body>
   
     <div>
            <button id='btnStart' class ="button">Launch New WIndow</button> 
     </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is where the `window.open()` redirects to.

```
example2.html

<html>

  <head>

     <title>My page 2</title>

     <script>src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" 
     </script>

     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

     <script>

            //Printing log to check if DOM is loaded
            $( document ).ready(function() {

                console.log( "Ready" );
            
            });
             
            //Load your function/script to execute here
            $(document).ready(function(){
               
                //Your function goes here or the script you wanna run
             
             });
                
  </head>

</html>
```

**Conclusion**

This tutorial demonstrates on how to open a new window(not tab) on button click and execute a javascript function and or script on opening the window.

Regards